# executePendingTransactions does not commit FragmentTransaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have some simple code, where I am replacing a fragment with another fragment. The problem I have seen is that the new fragment never has any of its create /attach etc lifecycles called.

The code is as follows:

```
String SERVER="SERVER";
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();      
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit );


Fragment s = fm.findFragmentByTag(SERVER);
if(s == null ) s = new ServerFragment();

ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, s, SERVER);
ft.show(s); 
ft.commit();
boolean result = fm.executePendingTransactions();
//Validate if added
Fragment frag = fm.findFragmentByTag(SERVER);
frag.isAdded(); //Returns FALSE!
```

I would expect the isAdded method to return True and critically I would also expect the usual Fragment lifecycle methods to be invoked. This however is not the case.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated?

Regards

Comment: None of the solutions have worked, any further thougts?

Answer (score 0):

not positive here, but it seems like since you're creating a new Fragment each time and not explicitly destroying the old ServerFragments, it's likely that findFragmentByTag is finding the first Fragment created, which would not return true for isAdded() since it's been removed from the view hierarchy.

If that's correct, then you should see the isAdded() call return true the very first time that method is called, and not again after that

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. This could be plausible, actually I am finding that the above is working in ceratain scenarios and not in others. I wrote a couple of test cases and in the second test case it fails. So your point about it working first time could make sense. I will try to explicitly destroy (have to work out how?) and let you know how it goes.

Comment: ACtually I have checked my code and it has a guard to check if the fragment already exists. Only if it does not exist does it create a new fragment. If a fragment was previously removed would it be destroyed automatically?

Comment: i thought remove() just removes it from the container, so if you've used  findFragmentByTag() somewhere and saved the Fragment object then it would still be around,..
Maybe when you check that s==null, you could destroy it when s!=null (or while() for that matter )

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a function to execute pending transactions that has the word immediate in it. It makes the transaction happen immediately rather than when the program gets to it.

Comment: Can't find such a function, the docs imply that executePendingTransactions does precisley this as opposed to commit which queues it.